# Datatables managing empty JSON results from server

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables

I'm using Datatables to fill a table on my web page following server JSON result, but if the JSON is empty (for instance if the session is timed out) I have alert messages that I would need to avoid.

here is my code:

```
$('#datatable-table').DataTable({
                "oLanguage": {
                    "sProcessing":     "Traitement en cours...",
                    "sSearch":         "Recherche&nbsp;:",
                    "sLengthMenu":     "_MENU_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
                    "sInfo":           "&eacute;l&eacute;ment _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments",
                    "sInfoEmpty":      "&eacute;l&eacute;ment 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 &eacute;l&eacute;ment",
                    "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtr&eacute; de _MAX_ &eacute;l&eacute;ments au total)",
                    "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Chargement en cours...",
                    "sZeroRecords":    "",
                    "sEmptyTable":     "",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst":      "Premier",
                        "sPrevious":   "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
                        "sNext":       "Suivant",
                        "sLast":       "Dernier"
                    }   
                },
                ajax: '../GetAllUsers',
                    columns: [
                        { "data": "id_user" },
                        { "data": "email" },
                        { "data": "telephone" }
                    ]
            });
```

would you please tell me how I can avoid any error message if result from GetAllUsers call is empty ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [Technical note #7](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/7).

> If you are willing to accept the error (for example if you cannot alter the backend system to fix the error), but don't want your end users to see the `alert()` message, you can change DataTables' error reporting mechanism to `throw` a Javascript error to the browser's console, rather than alerting it. This can be done using:
>
> ```
> $.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
> ```

See [`$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/$.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode) for more details.